# Regex - Match repeated character not in sequence

Tags: javascript, regex

Is there a way to match repeated characters that are *not* in a sequence?

Let's say I'm looking for **at least** two 6s in the string.

```
var string = "61236";
```

I can only find [quantifiers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions#Using_Special_Characters) that match either zero or one or characters in a sequence.

Thanks.

Comment: Can they be in sequence as well?

Comment: Yes. But does not have to.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is a regexp that matches a character that is followed somehwere in the string by the same digit:

```
/(.)(?=.*?\1)/
```

Usage:

```
var test = '0612364';
test.match(/(.)(?=.*?\1)/)[0] // 6
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/xU1rG4/4

Here is one that matches it repeated at least 3 times (total of 4+ occurances)

```
/(.)(?=(.*?\1){3,})/
```

DEMO: https://regex101.com/r/xU1rG4/3

Comment: Maybe add a lazy qualifier so that the `.*` doesn't match all the way to the right before looking for a backreference match: `/(\d)(?=.*?\1)/`

Comment: @MikeSamuel Added, thanks. I can't seem to add a maximum amount of occurances to the regex. Does anyone have any ideas? I tried [^\1] instead of ., but that is the character 1, tried {3,5}, but that just matches the \d with ..

Comment: to match a maximum, you need to ensure that the `.*?` does not match `\1`: `(?:(?!=\1).)*?`

Comment: Awesome! It works. Thank you! Damn you guys are fast.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I tried that in the meantime, but it doesn't seem to work: http://regex101.com/r/iL2dQ1 Perhaps i made a stupid mistake?

Comment: You should update your regex101 link. It does not show exactly the queries you are trying here now. I tried to fix it until I realized the earlier version was also incorrect.

Comment: @Matt The original link was for the generic regex101 sample, so when you edited it and created a new version, the original link pointed towards your version. I fixed it and added another version for the last example.

Comment: I didnt change the link at all or save a new version. The first DEMO still does not match the code you have show here (which I was trying to fix but became hesitant). It does match an _earlier_ version of this answer though.

Answer (score 3):

Have a try with this regex:

```
/(.).*?\1/
```

Answer (score 0):

Match 6 and anything up until another 6

```
!!"61236".match("6.*6")
// returns true
```

Match 6 and anything up until another the same as the first group (which is a 6)

```
!!"61236".match(/(6).*\1/)
// returns true
```

Comment: What are those !! doing in the beginning? Is that js?

Comment: @KarlPokus it converts the value returned by match to a boolean. If a match is found, the resulting array gets converted to true, otherwise null gets converted to false.

Answer (score 0):

Characters that are not in sequence and appear more than once:

```
/(.)(.+\1)+/
```